# Javascript webapp CSS3 animation

Tags: jquery, css, web-applications, animation, mootools

I've been searching for a simple jquery animation library for my mobile webapp

Basically, I wanted to have the "Flip" (flipboard) and "Slide" (flipboard, Android like slide in/out, old div scales down and fade out) animations and is touch ready!

Being touch ready means that the animation can trigger by user's interactions, touchstart, touchmove, touchcancel, touchEnd->autoplay, touchEnd->reverse...etc

There are a lot of CSS3 animation library there but i cannot find anything support touches like i mentioned above, so are there anything out there will fulfill the requirements?

btw doesn't matter jquery or mootools
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's builtin animation, you should be able to do it quite a bit of sophisticated animation. If you need more, I'd look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

But just to do a simple slide-in-out, position the element off-screen, then animate in onto the screen when desired.

```
$('.content').css({
  position: 'absolute',
  left: '100%',
  top: 0,
  height: $(window).height()',
  width: $(window).width(),
}
```

The to slide it in, animate the `left` property to `0`:

```
$('.content').animate({
  left: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dealing with mobile only i would use `zepto.js` its smaller than jQuery and supports

both touch events http://zeptojs.com/#Touch

and animation with CSS transform properites http://zeptojs.com/#animate

Its the *same* as jQuery give or take a few methods to keep zepto slim :)

Answer (score 0):

And representing the mootools side among all jquery kiddies you can look at [MoobileJS](http://moobilejs.com/) - it's pretty solid as a full js framework for mobile and it has what you requested

Comment: whoa no need to get all postal, i like mootools as well :) thanks for the mobile tip